# How to increase the width and height of an picture?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-drawable, android-theme, android-background

I have an activity with **no** layout. I set it like a theme directly in `AndroidManifest`:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

My theme contains only a background:

```
<style name="MyTheme"
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

And this is the background file which contains only one item:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The `ic_launcher` is the icon that has different sizes (hdpi, mdpi etc). The problem is that if I set the `width` and `height` to `200dp`, the item gets bigger but the image remains small. If I set the `width` and `height` to the `bitmap` nothing happens.

How to increase the width and height of the actual picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You this scenario you should try using a `Vector Image` for a proper quality for any height or ratio.